# Existence of weak solutions of a parabolic PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Assume that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n(n\geq3)$ is a bounded open set with smooth boundary, $\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega)$, $F(t)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and $F'$ is bounded. Given a PDE 
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t-\displaystyle{\sum}_{i,j=1}^na^{ij}(x)u_{x_ix_j}=F(u)&\text{a.e. }(x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T],\\u|_{t=0}=\varphi&\text{in }L^2(\Omega)
\end{cases}
$$
where the matrix function $[a^{ij}(x)]_{n\times n}\in C^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ is positive definite and symmetric. I want to know that if there exist a weak soluton $u\in L^{\infty}(0,T;H^1_0(\Omega))\cap L^2(0,T;H^2(\Omega))$ such that $u_t\in L^2(\Omega\times(0,T])$. If it exists, how to prove it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Start by showing that there exists a weak solution with lower regularity (standard $L^2$ energy), i-e
$$
u\in C([0,T];L^2)\cap L^2(0,T;H^1_0)
\qquad\mbox{with}\qquad
u_t\in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}).
$$
(This can be achieved opening any textbook about quasilinear parabolic equations.)

Then improve the regularity: since $F$ is Lipschitz it is easy to see that
$$
f:=F(u)\in L^2(0,T;L^2)
$$
hence $u$ is a weak solution of the frozen Initial-Boundary-Value problem
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
u_t+Lu=f & \mbox{in }Q_T\\
u=0 & \mbox{on } [0,T]\times \partial\Omega\\
u|_{t=0}=\varphi & \mbox{in }\Omega
\end{array}
\right.
$$
with $\varphi\in H^1_0$ and $f\in L^2(0,T;L^2)$, as well as $L$ a good, smooth, uniformly elliptic operator. Standard results (improved regularity) for this linear problem gives the desired regularity for $u$ (see e.g. Evans' book "PDEs" section 7.1.3).